# 2 Like buttons- one for the site, one for the post- how to?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This is for a wordpress site, but it could be for any.  I want a like button at the top of the page to 'like' the whole site.  I also want a like button at the end of a post to like that post.

Ok, I get that I can create two iframe buttons, using just the site url and the post url.  What i dont get is how to set up the meta tags.  eg, the image field would be different (site logo vs. post image)

Furthermore, I can imagine that it would be usefull to have even more like buttons, eg on a page that listed several posts, a like button on each.  I realize that too many iframes will slow or stop the browser.

Mostly i just need 2 buttons, with 2 sets of info.

Comment: Ok, so site.com/postname has tags for the post and site.com has sitewide tags, and the sitewide 'like'(top of post page) just points home. Right?
and the site.com/postname 'like' points to its self?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add two like buttons.

for site url button set up meta tags in your home page.

for post url set up meta tags in your post page.